# Increment every 33 line of 6 column by 1

Tags: python, shell, awk

I have file of the following type,

```
ATOM      4  C4  UNK X   1       7.747   4.310   5.563  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  C5  UNK X   1       8.900   3.705   6.021  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  C6  UNK X   1       9.622   2.872   5.185  1.00  0.00           C
```

-- upto 3564 lines.

I want to increase the sixth column by 1 every 33 lines. I have seen earlier posts and found this code,

```
gawk -v n=1 '
match($0,/^(.{22})....(.*)/, f) {printf "%s%4d%s\n", f[1], n, f[2]}
NR % 20 == 0 {n++}
{print}
' file
```

The output from the above file is :

```
ATOM   3556  H10 UNK X 178      30.121  19.518  46.272  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM   3556  H10 UNK X   1      30.121  19.518  46.272  1.00  0.00           H
```

Could suggest me , how to increase sixth column every 33 lines?

Comment: The code you've included seems pretty unrelated to what you're trying to do! Also, it looks like the input and output don't really match up.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the input and output match up. It's possible that all you need is a very simple awk command but until you make your question clearer, it's impossible for us to know. Which part are you stuck with, anyway?

Comment: Instead of posting 3 lines of input, telling us you want to increment every 33 lines and not showing any expected output - show, say, 10 lines of input and ask us how to increment every 3 lines and show the desired output for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increment only the (33*n)th rows, you can do this.

```
awk '!(NR%33){$6+=++p} 1'
```

line 33 will be incremented by 1, line 66 by 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might be sufficient:

```
awk '{$6=int(NR/33)+1}1' input.txt
```

This replaces field 6 with the an integer based on the line number.  The expression is kind of obvious.  The `+1` is there because, for example, on line 21, NR/33=0.6363, which `int()` truncates to zero.

And the trailing `1` at the end of the "script" prints the line because it evaluates to "true", and in awk, a missing statement defaults to `{print}`.

Note that in awk, whenever you change fields data, awk reprocesses the line to reduce whitespace, replacing all your field separators with `OFS`.

Comment: Thanks you all for a reply. The code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want but without testable sample input and expected output we're just guessing:

```
awk '{$6+=val; print} !(NR%33){++val}' file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
ATOM      4  C4  UNK X   1       7.747   4.310   5.563  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  C5  UNK X   1       8.900   3.705   6.021  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  C6  UNK X   1       9.622   2.872   5.185  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  C4  UNK X   1       7.747   4.310   5.563  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  C5  UNK X   1       8.900   3.705   6.021  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  C6  UNK X   1       9.622   2.872   5.185  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  C4  UNK X   1       7.747   4.310   5.563  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  C5  UNK X   1       8.900   3.705   6.021  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  C6  UNK X   1       9.622   2.872   5.185  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  C4  UNK X   1       7.747   4.310   5.563  1.00  0.00           C

$ awk '{$6+=val; print} !(NR%3){++val}' file
ATOM 4 C4 UNK X 1 7.747 4.310 5.563 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 5 C5 UNK X 1 8.900 3.705 6.021 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 6 C6 UNK X 1 9.622 2.872 5.185 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 4 C4 UNK X 2 7.747 4.310 5.563 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 5 C5 UNK X 2 8.900 3.705 6.021 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 6 C6 UNK X 2 9.622 2.872 5.185 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 4 C4 UNK X 3 7.747 4.310 5.563 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 5 C5 UNK X 3 8.900 3.705 6.021 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 6 C6 UNK X 3 9.622 2.872 5.185 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 4 C4 UNK X 4 7.747 4.310 5.563 1.00 0.00 C
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you the Python code, install [Python 3.4](http://python.org/) in order to run it.

```
import shutil
import os
with open("full_path_to_file", "r") as f, open("a.csv", "a") as w:
    count = 2
    l = next(f)
    l = l.split(",")
    l = str(int(l[5]) + 1)
    w.append(','.join(l))
    for line in f:
        if count % 33 != 0 or count <= 33:
            count += 1
            w.write(line)
        line = line.split(",")
        line[5] = str(int(line[5]) + 1)
        w.write(','.join(line))
       count += 1
    shutil.move(w.name, f.name)
    os.remove(w.name)
```

Comment: Did you test your code? Why did you import `csv` ad you didn't use it? The Condition will only match The 33 first line and the lines `% 33` So for example you will edit line number `54`? and the OP didn't ask for that?

Comment: I will not edit `54`. I edited the post and forgot to take out csv, sorry. And the OP wants every 33 line, I can use a `next(file)` to get the first line and parse it which I will do now. I